# I need help with an animation i'm doing

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, animation

I am doing a animation for my school, but for some reason whenever I go into render view or I try to render the animation my mesh plane doesn't show up, and 
I haven't hidden it and I also haven't moved it to a different layer
Please help asap!
Edit: Thanks for taking interest in my problem, here are the photos you asked for!
[image]
[image]

Comment: hard to tell, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)